# Seats Reservation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a seat reservation using the 2d arrays. I've got a problem wherein the output doesn't seem right and I don't know what to do with it. I've tried it multiple times but still doesn't get it right. I just want to put the asterisk inside the 2d table or inside the rows and columns. The asterisk represents as the seats.

```
public class BusSeatReservation {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tBUS SEAT RESERVATION");
        char [][] matrix = new char [11][10];

        for (int col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
            System.out.print("\t\tCol " + (col) + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
            System.out.println("Row " + (row) + "\t|");

            for (int seat = 1; seat <= 4; seat++) {
                matrix [row] [seat] = '*';
                System.out.print(matrix [row] [seat] + "\t\t");

            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

[image: and that was the output of my code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing tabulators and new lines at the wrong places within the loops but the major problem with your code are the array indices and matrix size. You can easily solve that by using variables for number of rows and columns.

```
public class BusSeatReservation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\t\t\tBUS SEAT RESERVATION");
        int rows = 10;
        int cols = 4;

        char[][] matrix = new char[rows][cols];

        System.out.print("\t\t");
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            System.out.print("\tCol " + (col+1));

        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.print("Row " + (row+1) + "\t|\t");

            for (int seat = 0; seat < cols; seat++) {
                matrix[row][seat] = '*';
                System.out.print(matrix[row][seat] + "\t\t");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for that. May I know why did you make it "(row+1)" and "(col+1)??

Comment: The arrays indices in Java start with zero but you tried to print "Row 1" or "Col 1".